# Socks proxies over SSH show same IP

Tags: ssh, proxy, ip, vps

I have recently been setting up proxies via SSH on my VPS and when I connect the non main IP via a browser and look at my IP, it shows up as the main IP, is there any way i can fix this?

For example, the main IP Address on my VPS is `123.123.12.32`. But I connect to the proxy with the IP `123.123.12.45` which are both the the same VPS, but instead of showing `123.123.12.45` it will show `123.123.12.32`.

Basically I want it to show the IP I have connected to, and not the main IP of the VPS.

I hope you understand

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the proxy connection through ssh to your VPS, all the proxies connections will be started as a new connection from the proxied server, which will always use the main IP address.

You can create firewall rules that could force the connection to go out using the second IP address though.

Comment: Okay, so is there anyway I can change this?

Comment: How can I create the firewall rules?

Thanks,

Comment: You can set manual firewall rules though script to force connections started by your logged user to use the second IP address.

Comment: Depends on the operating system used in the VPS. Is it Linux?

Comment: Yes it is, Debian. I could use Dante, but I had trouble trying to get it to use multiple IP's.

Comment: You can put the following in a shell script and run when needed: `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $USER -j MARK --set-mark 0x80`;
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x80 -j SNAT --to-source $IP_ALIAS`

Answer (score 0):

Re-answering, since previous answer is almost the same :)

In addition to the previous answer I see some options for you here

You can try using "tunnel" option for ssh authorized_keys file per each user.

> tunnel="n"
>
> Force a tun(4) device on the server.
> Without this option, the next available device will be used if the client requests a tunnel.

And then start playing with the knowledge of tunnel number and username to feed it to iptables.

As totally different solution you can try using something like OpenVPN to assign each user with local IP and then NAT that IP(or group of it) to any of external one. But this might be inapplicable for your case.